# Mathematics for cryptography.

Tags: cryptography

Besides number theory, what other areas should I study for crypto. I did my undergrad in Comp Sci so the crypto course didnt have much mathematical topics. But for a grad specilisation in crypto I need to get acquainted with the required mathematical skills.

Any sort of help is appreciated.

Regards
Rahul

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36906/good-books-on-abstract-algebra-and-cryptography-for-self-study.

Answer (score 1):

See the book [An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography](http://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/MathCryptoHome.html) by Hoffstein, Pipher, and Silverman.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to have a go at probability theory and information theory. These two (with a big emphasis on the first) pop up all around modern cryptography as most security proofs deal with showing that certain events are very very unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Besides number theory, you should also know some abstract algebra. A lot of modern cryptography is based on for example [elliptic curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography).

You could also check out [quantum cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_cryptography). This would require that you know some quantum mechanics.

Hope this helps.