# Good book on Rings, Fields and Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm a second year university student and I'm looking for a book that covers Linear Algebra in the context of Rings, with contents on things like applying quotient spaces, isomorphism theorems and rings to linear algebra ideas like Triangular, Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, Jordan Normal and Dual spaces.

I struggle with pure maths so would prefer a less abstract read if possible

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142325/good-book-for-a-comprehensive-course-in-modern-algebra-categories-modules-gro) for rings and fields in general, and similar posts for linear algebra, i.e., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804716/very-good-linear-algebra-book). Serge Lang's book on Linear algebra is written in the context of rings etc., as you want.