# Differences between the major abstract algebra books

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I currently have Dummit and Foote, but I was thinking of getting another textbook on abstract algebra to complement it. I've come across a few popular titles, but I'm not sure if they're different enough from D&F. What are your thoughts on the differences and approachability of the major abstract algebra books? Some of the popular titles that I've seen are:

- Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote
- A First Course in Abstract Algebra by Fraleigh
- Algebra by Artin
- Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Gallian
- and any other book you recommend

Comment: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54839/good-abstract-algebra-books-for-self-study) has a lot of advice in this vein, and has descriptions of a fair number of algebra books.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49253/requesting-abstract-algebra-book-recommendations)

Comment: I can at least say that the presentation in Artin's *Algebra* is quite different from Dummit and Foote. He focuses much more on linear algebra and representation theory early in the book: he doesn't even define rings until chapter 10! I think Dummit and Foote is a really great textbook, though, and could serve you well as a reference for years and years. That's been my experience, at least. Another possibility is Lang, which is even more encyclopedic, but also less reader-friendly.