# What is the best way to master my algebra skills without taking an algebra class?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, self-learning, recreational-mathematics, learning

I was in advanced math my entire life. I got through all the math I needed for my original degree. 8 years later here I am changing degrees and I need more math. I just took calculus I and I passed it. Calculus seems to be very easy in the sense that you just follow formulas. I understand it however I really am struggling with the algebra part of it which I never had in the past. I think I just need a refresher. Is there an app or a website that will do this for me that you would recommend?? I really don't want retake a class. And no, I no longer have old algebra school books.

Comment: This might be useful to you. 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/good-books-for-self-studying-algebra

Comment: From what you describe, it seems to me you should really start studying algebra yourself, in class or from some book/course (there are online courses). Thinking that "an app or a website that will do this for [you]" is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: You could use [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) to review what you've forgotten.  That said, I would recommend working through I. M. Gelfand's text Algebra.

Comment: You're seventeen, did advanced math, got a degree, but find algebra difficult? Could you give a bit more of context here?

Comment: If you would like to challenge yourself, then one option is to learn/review-by-posting/teaching on expii.com (click on the search bar and follow the clicks "Math -> Algebra" to see the organized concept map for Algebra). Let me know if you have questions (message or email is fine if you prefer)!