# Basic but rigorous book for Abstract Algebra and Topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

Could you recommend me a basic but rigorous book for Abstract Algebra and also another one for Topology? 
It'd be really great if it has a solution manual, or at least a great amount of solved problems. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think each part of your question has been asked before seperately

Comment: Might be useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/good-books-for-a-high-schooler-self-studying-abstract-algebra. Similarly, you can search for topology on MSE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Good books for a high schooler self-studying Abstract Algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/good-books-for-a-high-schooler-self-studying-abstract-algebra)

Comment: Thank you pals. Can you suggest me a basic but rigorous book for Topology, please?

Answer (score 1):

I personally really like the following book for learning abstract algebra: *Contemporary Abstract Algebra* by Joseph Gallian. It is a very good undergraduate level book for learning basics of algebra. It does have solution manuals available and also has answers for some of the questions in the back.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I found a solution manual for your book on this link: 
[link] (http://libgen.io/search.php?req=Joseph+Gallian&open=0&res=25&view=simple&phrase=1&column=def)

That page has almost every single english book that I read. Could you suggest me something for Topology, please?