# Literature on finite fields??

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

Finite fields occupy an important and elementary part of number theory, but I can’t seem to find good literature on this topic. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hachenberger, Jungnickel, "Topics in Galois Fields"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good books for a high schooler self-studying Abstract Algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/good-books-for-a-high-schooler-self-studying-abstract-algebra)

Comment: It really depends on your level of studies and focus of interest.  Your Question would be improved by adding such context.  For example, a reference that explores polynomial irreducibility over finite fields using computer algebra software might be useful if you have sufficient background and interest.

Comment: Any comprehensive graduate abstract algebra textbook.  Hungerford, Dummit & Foote, etc.

Comment: See https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/finite-fields/75BDAA74ABAE713196E718392B9E5E72

Answer (score 3):

I found *[Introduction to finite fields and their applications](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/introduction-to-finite-fields-and-their-applications/84CD611976678E270A2146652E1773D6#fndtn-information)* by R. Lidl and H. Niederreiter very helpful.

**Update:**
This book (or better a successor version) is also available as volume 20 in the Cambridge series *Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications* indicating its high quality status.

It is titled *[Finite Fields](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01CEKKB20)*. The first six chapters are essentially the same. Chapter V has been extended by three sections: Jabobi Sums, Character Sums with Polynomial Arguments and Further Results on Character Sums. The final four sections have been extended and somewhat rearranged.

Answer (score 0):

*Fried, Michael D.; Jarden, Moshe*, Field arithmetic, Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete. 3. Folge 11. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-22811-X/hbk). xxii, 780 p. (2005). [ZBL1055.12003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1055.12003).

Is the book many experts use.